# How do I simplify a hypothesis of the form True -> P in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic

If I have a hypothesis in my proof context that looks like `H: True -> P` and I want to convert it to `H: P`, what's the easiest way to do this? I tried `simpl in H` but it does nothing, and the only way I've found is the extremely unsatisfactory `pose proof (H Coq.Init.Logic.I) as H`. Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two ways to work with this, besides using `pose proof`.

#### Using `specialize`.

This tactics allows you to provide arguments to you hypotheses.
In you case you could do

```
specialize (H I).
```

or even

```
specialize H with (1 := I).
```

and you can use `as` if you want to create a copy rather than instantiate `H` directly.

#### Using `forward`.

I think this is what you want here. `forward H.` will ask you to prove the first hypothesis of `H`. So you will do something like this:

```
forward H.
- auto.
- (* Then resume with H : P *)
```

but you can also provide it with a (goal-closing) tactic:

```
forward H by auto.
(* Now you have one goal, and H has type P *)
```

`forward` is—as of yet—not part of the standard library. It can however be defined pretty easily (here is the definition from the MetaCoq library).

```
Ltac forward_gen H tac :=
  match type of H with
  | ?X -> _ => let H' := fresh in assert (H':X) ; [tac|specialize (H H'); clear H']
  end.

Tactic Notation "forward" constr(H) := forward_gen H ltac:(idtac).
Tactic Notation "forward" constr(H) "by" tactic(tac) := forward_gen H tac.
```

---

Note that `simpl` here doesn't work because it's not really a tactic to simplify hypotheses in the usual sense, it's really just a tactic to apply some computation rules, it basically evaluates the goal or the hypothesis you apply it on. `True -> P` does not reduce to `P` because it would then take one fewer argument.

Comment: Do I need to import something to use the `forward` tactic? I'm getting `Error: The reference forward was not found in the current environment.`

Comment: I was using it without knowing it was part of the stdlib! I will edit my answer to provide its definition, sorry!

Comment: Why not add a section with asset?  `assert (H := H I).`

And perhaps explain why `simpl` is not an option in this setting?

Comment: I do explain why `simpl` is not an option, or do you think it needs more details? I wasn't aware or `assert (H := H I)`.

Comment: According to the definition, it behaves as `specialize` in that case so I don't really see the point, it's just a confusing way of writing it. https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacn.assert

Comment: What is the difference here between `specialize` and `pose`?

Comment: `specialize (h x)` will replace hypothesis `h` with its application to `x`. `pose (h x)` will create a *new* hypothesis.