# Case splitting on if-then-else condition

Tags: coq

This is a silly beginner question, but how do I prove this theorem?

```
Open Scope Z.
Theorem test : forall x y:Z, (x > 0 -> y = 1) \/ (x <= 0 -> y = 2) -> y >= 1.
Proof.
  intros.
  destruct x.
  destruct H.
  (* stuck *)
Qed.
```

What I'm really trying to do is model an if-then-else statement as a Prop and case split on the condition to prove it. I get stuck with the context like this:

```
y: nat
H: 0 > 0 -> y = 1
-----------------
(1/3)
y >= 1
(2/3)
y >= 1
(3/3)
y >= 1
```

I sort of understand that to get rid of impossible cases, I need to find a contradiction in the hypothesis, but how do I do that here?

Advice on how this could be done better is welcome, e.g. is this the best way to model if-then-else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how do I prove this theorem?
>
> ```
> Theorem test : forall x y:Z, (x > 0 -> y = 1) \/ (x <= 0 -> y = 2) -> y >= 1.
> ```

Your theorem is not true.

Suppose `H: x > 0 -> y = 1` but `x` is actully `0`, then you have no way of proving `y >= 1` as you know nothing about `y`.

Perhaps you meant to use `and` (`/\`) instead of `or`?  Then here's one proof that uses `lia` to do the tedious `Z` arithmetic.

```
Require Import ZArith Lia. Open Scope Z.
Theorem test : forall x y:Z, (x > 0 -> y = 1) /\ (x <= 0 -> y = 2) -> y >= 1.
Proof.  intros x y [H1 H2]. enough (x>0 \/ x<=0) as [H|H]; lia. Qed.
```

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed the problem. Side question, just for my own learning: is it important that we know how to do the "tedious Z arithmetic" part without lia? My understanding is we would rewrite `0 <= 0` to True and then [simplify](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60817708) the hypothesis, but I got stuck when trying to do this also.

Comment: The term `0 <= 0` is indeed a true proposition, but it cannot be rewritten to `True` (propositions are types, and as such they do not satisfy a lot of equations, contrarily to inhabitants of inductive types). Instead you can either look in the library for lemmas that can prove your goal using the `Search` command, or directly use the tactic `reflexivity` as `<=` has been declared as a reflexive relation in the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is the lemma

```
Z_lt_le_dec : forall x y : Z, {x < y} + {y <= x}
```

of the library. What `{ … } + { … }` means is similar to `\/`, i.e. it is a kind of disjuction, but here this disjuction constructs a type in `Set` rather than `Prop`. This means that while you cannot use a `\/` disjuction to build a function returning a `nat` (because of Coq’s enforcement that propositions should be irrelevant) you *can* use a `{ … } + { … }` one. You can write

```
Definition test (x : Z) := if (Z_lt_le_dec 0 x) then 1 else 2.
```

which is syntactic sugar for a pattern matching like this one

```
Definition test (x : Z) := match (Z_lt_le_dec 0 x) with
  | left _ => 1
  | right _ => 2
end.
```

where `left` and `right` are the two constructors of `{ … } + { … }`.

To check that this `test` does what it should, you can now try to go and prove

```
Lemma test_ge1 (x : Z) : 1 <= test x.
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. The real problem was a bug in my theorem, but I tried this and it worked as well, will read up on sumbool and think about if I can incorporate this!